# Subscribing rabbitmq queue via Rebus 2

Tags: rabbitmq, rebus

In my application I am trying to subscribe 'MyQueue' queue which has bindings to it in 'Rebus' topic exchange basing on your advices using next code:

```
    async void InitializeBus()
    {

    var busConfigurer = Configure.With(new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(_container))
            .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
            .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(_connectionString, "MyQueue")
                .Declarations(false, false, false)
                    .ExchangeNames("RebusDirect", "Rebus")
                        .Prefetch(5))
            .Options(o => {
                o.SimpleRetryStrategy(_errorQueue);
                if (_enableLegacyCompatibility)
                {
                    o.EnableLegacyCompatibility();
                }
            })
            .Serialization(s => s.Decorate(c => new XmlMessageSerializer()));

        var bus = busConfigurer.Start();`
        await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("MyQueue");
    }
```

as a result i have an exception like

> The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
>   Peer, code=404, text="NOT_FOUND - no queue 'MyQueue' in vhost '/'",
>   classId=50, methodId=20, cause=

although the queue exists.

If I remove .Declarations(false, false, false) and await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("MyQueue"); it will create new MyQueue in rabbit in RebusDirect exchange and start listening to it. Connection string to rabbit is correct.

Where the problem could be? Improper configuration or incorrect subscription way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - you should probably only skip automatically declaring things if you are an expert Rebus and RabbitMQ user and there is something out-of-the-ordinary that you want to achieve.

There the `Declarations` part should probable be `.Declarations(true, true, true)` (or simply left out because the default is to always ensure that exchanges, queues, and bindings are automatically declared).

Next thing - the line

```
await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("MyQueue");
```

indicates that you are confusing things, because `MyQueue` is a queue, but when you `Subscribe` to something, you subscribe to a TOPIC.

A "topic" is basically just an arbitrary string, e.g. "thingamabob". A publisher can publish things using that topic like this:

```
await bus.Advanced.Topics.Publish("thingamabob", new GizmoDoodle());
```

which will then *deliver the `GizmoDoodle` message to the queues currently bound to that topic*.

In order to "bind to the topic", you

```
await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("thingamabob");
```

which establishes the binding in RabbitMQ.

I suggest you start out with a clean slate (without customizing Rebus' use of RabbitMQ in any way) and go see what Rebus creates in RabbitMQ to make it work. And if you haven't done it already, you definitely should go enable the [RabbitMQ Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).

Comment: Probably I didn't catch your point right but if I don't want to archive something extraordinary. I have been using Rebus 1 and now switching to 2 version. My goal is to continue the way of messaging that already exists in application. If I remove `.Declarations(false, false, false)` it will create new MyQueue in rabbit in RebusDirect exchange and start listening to it. All i need is make my application listening existing queue in Rabbit which has bindings in existing topic exchange and invoke existing IHandleMessages<T>

Comment: What you want to achieve is pretty extraordinary and definitely not supported (but you know that :) ) and I am not even sure it is possible (you also know that) ... what happens when you remove the `Declarations` line and use the `Rebus`/`RebusDirect` exchanges?

Comment: Excuse me if my question seems weird but in my case it is extremely important not to break existing logic but enjoy new rebus async approach.  As i mentioned if I remove `.Declarations(false, false, false)` it will create new MyQueue in rabbit in RebusDirect exchange and start listening to it. And the reason of it is RabbitMqTransport as i have seen from rebus code because it establishes binding to a queue through a DIRECT exchange `....  model.QueueBind(address, this._directExchangeName, address);....` . My existing exchange where routing keys are set is topic.

Comment: as far as I can tell, the only missing binding is the one that Rebus 1 expects from the `MyQueue` topic to the queue `MyQueue` - and I would believe that `await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("MyQueue")` establishes that

Comment: It has added a routing key to correct exchange looking on newly created 'MyQueue' queue with a samename routing_key "MyQueue". So proceeding with this approach i need to add all other required routing_keys into my topic exchange which will point on this queue. Can i do it programmaticaly while configuring bus (via `.Subscriptions(..)` or just calling multiple `bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("nth_routing_key");` ?

Comment: You should probably just call Subscribe with as many topics as you require

Comment: Ok i got it. In case of using `bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("routing_key")` What is the proper way to set mapping between routing key and `TType of my IHandleMessages<TType>`? so far non of existing handlers being executed upon receiving a message i suppose i missed seting up of incoming bindings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118464/discussion-between-takinosaji-and-mookid8000).

Comment: I have found possible reason of not dequeuing message. An exception says: `Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: unexpected exception thrown while trying to dequeue a message from rabbitmq, queue address: PIM.Input ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
 ...
   at Rebus.RabbitMq.RabbitMqTransport.CreateTransportMessage(BasicDeliverEventArgs result)
   at Rebus.RabbitMq.RabbitMqTransport.<Receive>d__32.MoveNext()`     Rebus1 successfully handled messages published not from rebus framework(no rebus headers etc), is that changed in 2nd version?

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: The problem was in absent message-header in a message. Previous version of RabbitMQTransport could not handle it, as we discussed on github and the problm was solved in your marvelous latest version of transport)

Comment: Excellent :) I would love it if you would mark the question as answered then – it looks good when almost all of the Rebus questions on SO are answered